# Rendering flow:interview

Tags: apex, visualforce, flow

I'm having a strange issue where a quite simple re-render of an output panel containing a flow is causing the flow to render without the standard "Next" button" The flow screen renders with the input fields, but no buttons. Scratching my head on this one.

```
<apex:page controller="FlowTestController">

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!flowVisible}">
        <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Show Flow" action="{!showFlow}" />
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!flowVisible}">
        <flow:interview  name="Account_Creation_Flow" interview="{!myFlow}" finishLocation="{!flowFinish}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>


</apex:page>

public class FlowTestController {

    public Integer numAccounts {get; set;}
    public Boolean flowVisible {get; set;}
    public Flow.interview.Account_Creation_Flow myFlow {get; set;}

    public FlowTestController() {
        flowVisible = false;            
    }

    public PageReference showflow() {
        flowVisible = true;
        return null;
    }

    public String getFlowFinish() {
        flowVisible = false;
        return null;
    }

}
```